# How to run org-mode commands from shell?

Tags: shell, emacs

I want to run the org-mode command via bash script. For instance, I have several org mode files to export to html under a project I defined. Then I sync files to web server etc. For this reason, without opening the emacs and exporting the files to html files, I would like to do it from bash script.

How can I run org-mode commands like

```
M-x org-publish-project
```

Then enter the project name let us say, trial_project. How can I do it within shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I publish a project like this:

```
emacs -batch --load publish-doc.el --eval '(org-publish "publish-doc")'
```

where `publish-doc.el` contains the definition of the "publish-doc" project. If you can ssh to your server, you can even have the `publishing-directory` be remote: org will use `tramp` to copy the files over.

`publish-doc.el` should initialize org-mode if necessary and define the project - the details might depend on whether you are using the org-mode that comes with emacs, or you are using upstream versions from MELPA or the git repo. But you should be able to mimic what you do in your normal initialization and get it going. In my case, I have to modify my load-path to find org, since I clone from the upstream git repo: you might not need that at all, but if you do need it, you will need to modify the path to where *your* org is loaded from. The following minimal `publish-doc.el` publishes a set of org files in `~/org` to `~/public_html` - this is adapted from an [example in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Simple-example.html#Simple-example) except that I had to add the publishing function:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/emacs/org/org-mode/lisp/")

(require 'org)
(require 'ox-html)

(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("org"
     :base-directory "~/org/"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html"
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :section-numbers nil
     :with-toc nil
     :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"
             href=\"../other/mystyle.css\"
             type=\"text/css\"/>")))
```

The command line invocation is then

```
 emacs -batch -l publish-doc.el --eval '(org-publish "org")'
```

HTH.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, when using `-batch`, you *must* load an initialization file: `-batch` implies `-q` so your `.emacs` or equivalent is *not* loaded. You *could* use `-l ~/.emacs` but that generally contains a lot of extraneous stuff, so when preparing a script to run from the command line, most people prefer to use a trimmed initialization file that includes only what's necessary for the task at hand (cf. the `publish-doc.el` file above).

Comment: I would like to export to local folder first and then sync the files to server via resync. However, when I run from shell 

`emacs --batch --eval '(org-publish-project "trial_project")'` 
I get following error "Symbol's function definition is void: org-publish". Can you explain more about the publish-doc.el?

Comment: Edited the answer to add an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info but I still have the problem. The functions that you mentioned  in publish-doc.el is defined in my .emacs file. 

Hence without loading the function, I run 
`emacs --batch --eval '(org-publish-project "org")' ` but I still get the error code "Symbol`s function definition is void: org-publish"

Comment: What version of org-mode are you running? Do you have the `(require ...)` lines included?

Comment: When I run the command in emacs, everything works fine. For instance in emacs, `M-x org-publish-project RET org` and all the org files converted to html files inside the defined folder. The only problem is that I cannot do it from shell command. I was going to send you the relevant part of my .emacs file but I cannot since it is too long for the comment. 
The version is (elpa) org-20170925/ . I added (require 'org) after your comment but still get the same warning.

Comment: You need to load the initialization explicitly on the command line: see the `-l` command I had above. When you use -batch, your .emacs is *not* loaded automatically. See [Initial options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got it now. 
 `emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs --eval '(org-publish "org")' ` worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. Generally speaking, `.emacs` contains a *lot* of stuff that is not relevant to the task at hand. That's why people strip the load file down to the minimum necessary to accomplish what's needed (that's why I have the publish-doc.el file).

Answer (score 1):

You can write an elisp function which opens the necessary buffers and then does the export. Then, if your emacs is running, you can use `emacsclient -e ...` to run the function. If your emacs is not running and you want to run your function directly from the command line, you can use `emacs --batch --eval ...`  to run your function.